# Application B is used by many client so which (Tools) will scale the B?

Tags: docker, microservices

So I have three micro-services (images A,B & C) in docker.
The only advantage of micro-service is scale it if required, In my case I would like to scale B.

So how to do the scaling (+ or -) of services when we have more demands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which tools will scale B?

The two main ones are:

- [**docker swarm**](https://docs.docker.com/swarm/) ([GitHub repo](https://github.com/docker/swarm)): see [docker/swarm-microservice-demo-v1](https://github.com/docker/swarm-microservice-demo-v1)
- **[Kubernetes](http://kubernetes.io/)** ([GitHub repo](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes)): see for instance "[Scaling Kubernetes Microservices on OpenStack](http://getcloudify.org/2016/04/04/scaling-kubernetes-microservices-openstack-TOSCA-orchestration-cloud-open-source.html)".

> The only advantage of micro-service is scale it if required

Not "the only advantage": it is also isolation, and better use of the host resources.

Comment: You are right it is also  isolation, and better use of the host resources, But my point was from a developer prospective  nothing changed , only thing he should create the small independent unit may be service, And the tools like   docker swarm the will increase the  performance of the apps by scalability.

Comment: @vaibhavsharma Don't forget to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer and http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote